# Azure App Service installation does not find my subscription

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I'm trying to install **Azure App Services** in a Xamarin.Droid project using Visual Studio for Mac 2017.
According to the walkthrough in https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/azure/connected-services/ at the point where I should select my Azure Subscription...

(the specific part of instructions is quoted below)

> 5.Once the dependencies have been added, you will be asked to log in with the account you want to use to communicate with Azure. If you’re
>   already logged in with a Microsoft ID, Visual Studio for Mac will
>   attempt to fetch your Azure subscriptions and any app services
>   associated with them. If you do not have any subscriptions, you can
>   add one by signing up for a free trial or purchasing a subscription
>   plan in the Azure portal.

.. the installer can not find my subscription, showing

> We couldn't find a subscription on your account
>   [my_valid_subscription_email] / Add a subscription to your account /
>   Check again

I can't go further that point.
(my Azure account is running ok, Internet connection OK...)

Any ideas or workaround? Thanks in advance for any help.